# Check if last character is a question mark in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
 function askQuestion(){
   var Prompt = prompt("What yes or no question do you have?", "Type it here...");
   var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1);
   if(Prompt  != null){
    if (number == 1){
     alert("Signs point yo yes.");
    }else if(number == 2){
     alert("Yes.");
    }else if(number == 3){
     alert("Reply hazy, try agian.");
    }else if(number == 4){
     alert("Doubtful.");
    }else if(number == 5){
     alert("All signs point to no.");
    }else if(number == 6){
     alert("Most Likely.");
    }else if(number == 7){
     alert("Absolutely.");
    }else if(number == 8){
     alert("It doesn't look good.");
    }
   }else{
    alert("Please re-ask the Magic 8 Ball.")
   }
  }
```

```html
  <body bgColor="Black">
    <center><img src="8ball.png" onClick="askQuestion()" style="cursor:pointer;"></center>
  </body>
```

This is what I have. What I would like to know, is how to see the text typed in the prompt has a question mark at the end.

Answer (score 3):

if Prompt is a string then it should just be as simple as

```
var lastChar = Prompt.slice(-1);
if(lastChar == '?') { .... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
if (Prompt.slice(-1) === "?") {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old answer (`substr()`):

```
var lastChar = (Prompt.trim().substr(-1) === '?')
```

New answer (`substring()`):

```
var lastChar = (Prompt.trim().substring(Prompt.length - 1) === '?')
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but just a FYI that `String.prototype.substr()` has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Good point, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the charAt() method:

```
var lastChar = Prompt.charAt(Prompt.length-1);
if (lastChar === "?") {
    // your logic here
}
```